# ASIHTTPRequest POST to TomCat

Tags: ios

When i use ASIHTTPRequest to "POST" to server URI, just response back "null".

URI: **"http://www.solok.com:8080/solok_interface/api/web/"** 
parameter: NSDictionary with key "content".

I try to use ASIHTTPRequest instead of ASIFormDataRequest, but there's no "setPostValue" method.

Any help, thanks!

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/solok_interface/api/web/"];
ASIFormDataRequest *req = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[req setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[req setPostValue:cipherString forKey:@"content"];
[req start];

NSError *error1 = [req error];
if (!error1) {
    NSString *reponse = [req responseString];
    NSLog(@"Response string is %@",reponse);
}

[req setDelegate:self];
[req setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"complete");
    NSString *responseString = [req responseString];
    NSLog(@"the string is %@",responseString);
    NSLog(@"The data is %@ %d",[req responseStatusMessage],[req responseStatusCode]);

}];
[req setFailedBlock:^{

    NSLog(@"@fail");
}];
```

Comment: Is there actually a value inside cipherString?

Comment: By the way , even if you solve this I recommend switching over from ASIHTTPRequest to AFNetworking as Ben himself recommended. As ASIHTTPRequest is no longer actively developed and no longer supported officially.

Comment: @Luke It's just a NSString, thanks.

Comment: I know that, but does it actually contain a value? That's the first thing I would check.

Comment: @Shai Mishali OK, i will consider that, thanks!

Comment: @Luke Yes, i am sure, just give it a content value in fact.

Comment: Figured out, not iOS part's trouble. thanks you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use ASIHTTPRequest anymore, the ASI team has stopped to support it. AFNetworking is the right choice for IOS developer.